# Notification doesn't appear to android 8+

Tags: java, android, notifications

With this code, I want to click in a button and appear a notification. The problem is when in click in my button doesn't appear when I test in emulator api 26+. In api below 26 appear normally without problems.

```
btNotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notification();
    }
});


public void notification() {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new 
        RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_collapsed);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Atividade");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.act, activity);
        remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.timer, chronometer.getBase(), chronometer.getFormat(), !running);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_time_24)
                .setContent(remoteViews)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notifManager != null;
        notifManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: If I do this with channel, will it work on api below 26?

Comment: Yes, it will work.